# Heroku load error on require?

Tags: ruby, heroku

My Ruby application runs fine on my nitrous.io box, but when I push it to Heroku and it attempts to run a scheduled process, the logs show this error:

```
2013-12-23T22:37:11.902160+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4283]: State changed from starting to up                                                                                                                  
2013-12-23T22:37:12.178751+00:00 app[scheduler.4283]:   from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require'                                                      
2013-12-23T22:37:12.178751+00:00 app[scheduler.4283]:   from /app/bin/rbtc:3:in `<main>'                                                                                                                    
2013-12-23T22:37:12.178751+00:00 app[scheduler.4283]: /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require': cannot load such file -- rbtc_arbitrage (LoadError)                                                                                                                                                                                                           
2013-12-23T22:37:13.432972+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4283]: Process exited with status 1                                                                                                                       
2013-12-23T22:37:13.461438+00:00 heroku[scheduler.4283]: State changed from up to complete
```

This is the code in /app/bin/rbtc:3

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rbtc_arbitrage'
RbtcArbitrage::CLI.start ARGV
```

[File structure link](http://imgur.com/QFd4RB0)

I tried changing this to `require_relative` as in a answer to someone else on Stack Overflow to no avail.

I'm kinda at a loss here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please post your folder structure and the code around `/app/bin/rbtc:3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, make sure that this file exists: `lib/rbtc_arbitrage.rb` which loads other files in your repo like this (syntax is valid if you are using bundler):

```
require 'rbtc_arbitrage/version'
require 'rbtc_arbitrage/file1'
# .. and so on
```

Now, adding this file should work alone, but if this does not work, try adding your `lib` directory to the LOAD PATH in your `bin/rbtc` file before any `require` statments, like this:

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib')
```

This explicitly tells ruby to add the `lib` directory to the load path, and should solve your problem.